# DateTime.TryParseExact and parsing multiple date formats

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I am trying to see if a string is a valid date. I am having trouble since the dates are in      "2011–7–17 23:18:52" format. I am testing like so:

```
String lstrTime = "2011–7–17 23:18:52";
DateTime datevalue; 
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(lstrTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", enUS,
                     DateTimeStyles.None, out datevalue))
                        {
                            rtxtOutput.Text += "Valid datetime: " + lstrTime;
                        }
```

I think the reason I am having trouble is because the date can have only 1 M value or 2 MM for months. I have bulk data to process, and changing out the M to MM wont happen.

Edit: I have tried all suggested link, perhaps it could be the cultureinfo not recognizing a 24 hour clock(questionmark)

Comment: FWIW, when I copy your code, the hyphens in `lstrTime` are character code 8211; the hyphens in the "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" are character code 45.  The TryParseExact call fails because of it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks to all of the contributors who helped me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 24-hour time which is a capital H, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Answer (score 0):

You could try the overload:

TryParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-tryparseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetime@)